# Under what conditions is the $f$-divergence a distance?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory

It is well known that the total variation is a distance, whereas the KL-divergence is not. I am wondering under what conditions on $f$, the induced $f$-divergence is a distance? Or consider a weaker proposition, when will $f$-divergence satisfy the triangle inequality?

Comment: I'd guess that this is highly constrained, since, other than TV, even the standard $f$-divergences that are sort of a metric aren't actually metrics (e.g. Hellinger squared is a $f$-divergence, although its square root is a metric. Similarly with Jensen-Shannon divergence). In any case, I would suppose one necessary condition is that $f(x) = x f(1/x)$ for all $x \ge 0,$ which derives from the symmetry condition (and some limiting arguments using judicious choices of $P,Q$). The triangle inequality similarly seems to require $f(x) \le f(y) + y f(x/y)$ for every $x,y$.